# Python update from 2.7.6 to 2.7.8 - did I just lose all my previously installed modules?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Title basically states it all. I upgraded my version of Python in order to hopefully play more nicely with Mac OS 10.9, but am now unable to use some modules I need for my work (`NumPy`, `Pandas`, `SciPy`, `Scikit-Learn`, etc.) Does this upgrade automatically wipe out any previously installed modules? Do I just need to install them again? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upgraded, it created a new `sitepackages` directory structure. Your packages are not installed any more, so yes you need to reinstall them into the new version.

Before you do that, take a good look at virtual environments rather than install the modules and packages globally.

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs will get you started, then google virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the reply and additional information.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you try out the anaconda python distribution. It comes with all of these packages pre-installed, and its free. Also, in addition to pip, you can use the `conda` package manager which is *much* better for scientific packages. See http://technicaldiscovery.blogspot.com/2013/12/why-i-promote-conda.html for an explanation.

With `conda`, you can install numpy/scipy/pandas/etc with `conda install numpy scipy pandas` and it just works, and takes about 10 seconds. No compilation necessary (OTOH `pip install scipy` can take over 15 minutes, requires a fortran compiler, and is generally very tricky).

link: http://continuum.io/downloads

Comment: I've used the anaconda distribution in the past, but may need to try it again. Thanks for this. Do you know if it comes with the Spyder IDE?

Comment: Yeah, I think it does.

Comment: One more question: will using the `conda install` command also install non-scientific stack modules? For instance, there's a statistical plotting module I really like, `seaborn`, and I'm wondering if I can install that with `conda`. Otherwise, would using `pip` ensure that new/other modules are installed in the `anaconda` directory? Any insight there would be super helpful.

Comment: Yes, seaborn is in the conda repos. And you can also use pip too -- just `conda install pip; pip install <whatever>`. There is also a service called binstar that's a little bit like pypi, where people can put up packages. You can set your conda to look for packages in these other channels. But by default, it just looks in the default channels maintained by the anaconda team, which are generally pretty extensive (but not as big as pypi).